# 502 bad gateway in nginx installed by Homebrew for using Homestead on Mac

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, homebrew, homestead

There are so many threads about this problem but none of them could help me.

I'll explain what I want, what I did and what is the problem (I think).

I want to install Homestead 3.1.0, No matter php, vagrant or nginx version (for me).

I've installed the last version of VirtualBox, Vagrant and Homebrew, nginx version 1.11.9 (through Homewbrew), php version 5 and 7 (through Homebrew). I modified /etc/hosts , I can't modify sites-enabled from nginx because the path doesn't exist.

The problem is when I insert homestead.app in the browser, nginx shows 502 bad gateway and I can't find the problem and I tried every post in StackOverFlow and it still doesn't work

What more info you need? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

You'll need to lock the version of the box down to a previous version by adding

version: 0.6.0

To your Homestead.yaml This will use the older .box file.

For example:

- ip: "192.168.10.10"
- memory: 2048
- cpus: 1
- hostname: homestead
- name: homestead
- provider: virtualbox
- version: 0.6.0

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/392)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually modify the nginx setup. You add your local URLs to the Homestead setup file (Homestead.yaml). For example:

```
folders:
    - map: /Developer/yourDevFolder
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: siteone.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/siteonefolder/public
    - map: sitetwo.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/sitetwofolder/public
```

Once you are done, you need to provision your vagrant vm so it will apply the changes:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

If you have already modified `/etc/hosts` that should be all you need to do.

Comment: Actually I did but it didn't work. This [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-start-nginx-job-for-nginx-service-failed) helped to me